# How to convert words to a date?

Tags: r

I have a df of dates that are in this format:  4 days ago, 
6 weeks ago, 8 months ago, 1 year ago.

I want to write a statement that checks first to see if it's month, week, year.  Then it extracts the number.  After that I do the appropriate calculation by subtracting from Sys.Date().  I've tried a couple different ways and can't get it to work.

Any chance you can help me with one and I can i figure out rest?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this crude function help you? It should work even for strings like `"3 years, 2 months ago"`. Returns `NA` if `month`, `year` or `day` do not appear in the string with a number in front.

```
library("stringr")

# Small helper function to convert NAs to zero and convert to numeric
na_to_zero <- function(x) { 
  x[is.na(x)] <- "0"
  return(as.numeric(x))
}

get_date_before_today <- function(d) {
  today <- Sys.Date()

  days   <- na_to_zero(str_extract(d, "(?i)[0-9]*(?= day\\D)"))
  months <- na_to_zero(str_extract(d, "(?i)[0-9]*(?= month\\D)"))
  years  <- na_to_zero(str_extract(d, "(?i)[0-9]*(?= year\\D)"))

  days_ago <- days + 365.25/12*months + 365.25*years
  date_before_today <- today - days_ago

  # If no matches were made, zeros are substituted for all, and hence days_ago is 0
  date_before_today[days_ago == 0] <- NA  

  return(date_before_today)
 }
```

Testing:

```
d <- c("4 months ago asds", "2 years ago", "1 day ago", "5 years, 3 months", "never")

get_date_before_today(d)
#[1] "2018-05-15" "2016-09-13" "2018-09-13" "2013-06-14" NA
```

Note, it does not give you exact dates per se. But I guess one can argue that, for example, 1 month ago can be ambiguous. What does 1 month ago mean exactly for if today is the 31st of October?

The "weeks" case can be added trivially.

Comment: This works too...  And is more my style.  I'll use both of them.  Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

We can patch together a few tidyverse functions to make quick work of this. Mostly using `lubrdate` for the date shifting, `stringr` for the string parsing, and `purrr` for the mapping. For example

```
mm <- stringr::str_match(x, "(\\d+) (day|week|month|year)s? ago")
shifter <- list(day=days, week=weeks, month=months, year=years)
shifts <- map2(mm[,3], as.numeric(mm[,2]), ~case_when(.x=="day"~days(.y),
                    .x=="week"~weeks(.y),
                    .x=="month"~months(.y),
                    .x=="year"~years(.y)))
map_dbl(shifts, ~today()-.x) %>% as_date
# [1] "2018-09-10" "2018-08-03" "2018-01-14" "2017-09-14"
# where today() returns [1] "2018-09-14"
```

Comment: This is great.  I tried all day to do this.  I'll study this when I get home.  wow